# getJSON return variable.. solution?

Tags: jquery

My function fetches if the user is banned and i want to return a variable that determines if a popup displays; but as I've found out you can't return a variable from a `getJSON` function.

```
 function fetchban() {
    $.getJSON('/fetchban.php',function(data) {

        if(data==0) {

            var banned =  data;
        } else {
            $.each(data,function(index,result) {
            $('#ban-prompt').html(result);
            $('.popup-background').show();
            $('#ban-container-2').show();
            });
        }

    });

    return banned;
}

$('.button').click(function() {
var banned = fetchban();

if(banned==0) {

//display-popup

}

});
```

There are alot of lines i call the `fetchban` function, so i would prefer the `getJSON` in a function.  What is the solution?

Comment: then why u using getJSON? use .get()

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery getJSON - Return value to the caller function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229307/jquery-getjson-return-value-to-the-caller-function)

Comment: or just set the banned flag inside the JSON, like {banned:"false",datas:{... your regular object}} and then go var banned = data.banned

Comment: That's one of the most duplicated question on SO. Just have to look at the right column to see some of the usual answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your function.

The first, and the most significant, is that it assumes that `getJSON` is synchronous. It is *asynchronous* by default, meaning it's impossible for `fetchban` to *return* a value based on the data retrieved. Instead, `fetchban` should accept a callback it calls with the result.

The second (which will go away anyway once you fix the first), is that you're trying to return a variable from `fetchban` that isn't declared (because you declare it *inside* your `getJSON` success handler).

So you'd change `fetchban` to look something like:

```
function fetchban(callback) {
    $.getJSON('/fetchban.php',function(data) {
        var banned;

        // ...figure out what `banned` should be from the `data`,
        // I'm afraid I couldn't make sense of the code, looked
        // like it always set `banned` to 0.

        // Call the callback with the result
        callback(banned);
    });
}
```

And then **instead of**:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var banned = fetchban();

    if(banned==0) {
        //display-popup
    }
});
```

do this:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    fetchban(function(banned) {
        if(banned==0) {
            //display-popup
        }
    });
});
```

...or **much better**, fetch it earlier so you *already* have that information when the `click` arrives. Users don't like delays when they click, and even the best case on a web round-trip is noticeable to human beings.

Comment: How do i do "fetchban should accept a callback it calls with the result"?

Comment: @user892134: See update. Or any of about 757,521 callback tutorials and examples on the web. ;-)